# C# Patching binary (jnz to jz) in memory

Tags: c#, assembly

I would like to patch a binary with a C#, change jnz to jz in memory. I found the address where jnz is stored (00411988) and I would like to patch this (75 3F) with (74 3F) which is jz. I tried using MemorySharp but it did not work.

```
var address = new IntPtr(0x00411988);
byte[] patch = { 0x74, 0x3F };

using (var m = new MemorySharp(Process.GetProcessById(id)))
{
    m[address].Write(patch);
}
```

I also tried using windows api to patch a process:

```
var address = new IntPtr(0x00411988);
byte[] patch = { 0x74, 0x3F };
var hProc = OpenProcess((uint)ProcessAccessFlags.AllAccess, false, (uint)process.Id);
    
int op = 0;
WriteProcessMemory(hProc, new IntPtr(address), patch, (UInt32)patch.LongLength, out op);
    
CloseHandle(hProc);
```

Photo of my code which I want to patch:
[image]

My goal is to patch this jnz with jz. I cannot really find what I am doing wrong. Could someone help and explain me how to do it?

Comment: `I cannot really find what I am doing wrong` - well you could start by looking at the statuses and error codes that you get back. -- You can't just open a memory page in another process and write to it, you need to change the access rights to do that successfully.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I played with breakpoints but I didn't get any error. Everything seemed to work fine, but after accessing my program which I want to patch the program was working still like it had jnz.

Comment: `I didn't get any error` - you didn't look for any, `WriteProcessMemory`, for example, returns a success status, and I am willing to bet $2 that it fails in your case.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yep, you're right :D it returned false. How can I find what's causing it to return false?

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: There is a Selector In the Microprocessor that is needed to get location of memory that is needed.  When an application gets loaded into memory (when started) the operating system assigns the Selector(s) in the EXE file to physical memory locations (kernel code) . So there are two issues 1) If you have a selector outside the current selector you need to have kernel privilege to access the selector 2) Managed c# when subroutines are called wrap the call with protection so subroutine are only allowed to access the memory areas they need on the execution stack.

Comment: I fixed the problems and now WriteProcessMemory is returning true, so everything is correct but my program is still not getting patched. :/ I guess @jdweng is right, but is there any other way to manipulate program to return success? I would like to do something like in [rastamouse](https://github.com/rasta-mouse/AmsiScanBufferBypass/blob/master/ASBBypass/Program.cs) amsi bypass but on my own program.

Comment: Why not just patch the program on disk?  Then you don't need any special permissions (except file write of course).

Comment: @Neil I guess you are right, I will try to do it.